# How to change bitrate mode: VBR to CBR with MPEG4 of H264 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-4, bitrate

I've tried to convert bitrate mode from VBR to CBR with FFMPEG library,but bitrate mode cannot change.
My command line:

`ffmpeg -i <in file> -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 320×240 -vcodec libx264 -b 96k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 96k -bufsize 96k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 320:240 -g 30 -async 2 <output file>`

I found some apps but don't have any app that i can change bitrate mode.
Can anyone point me why my cmd cannot change mode or the app can does that?.
I think CBR is a mode that bitrate is the same all time,it's true?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are just looking to get a Constant Bitrate? If so, adding `-minrate 96k` will probably do the trick

Comment: thanks Shawn, i added to cmd with -minrate and change -vcodec to mpeg4 then my problem solved.Thanks.